# PHP for loop formula

Tags: php, for-loop

I have this for loop that I am working on and there is a formula inside the for loop, 
First time when the loop runs the data is provided to it, but then after that the formula needs to take the last output in it

for example on first loop `$weekly_savings` is `500` but then after that the `$weekly_savings`should be equal to last output (`$FV`)

This is the code I am using but it is not giving me the correct results.

```
$weekly_savings = "100";
$goal = "5000";
$progress = "500"
$NPER = round(PHPExcel_Calculation_Financial::NPER(.002/12,($weekly_savings*4),($goal - $progress))*-1,2);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $NPER; $x++) {
    echo "<br>";
    $weekly_savings = $FV;
    echo $FV = round(PHPExcel_Calculation_Financial::FV(.002/12,1,$weekly_savings*4,$progress)*-1,2);
}
```

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply replace `$weekly_Savings` within the for loop by `$FV` and assign the value `500` to $FV right before the for loop.

The problem of your solution is, that at the first cycle `$weekly_savings` is assigned an empty `$FV` value (that should be NULL, or at least an empty string) you could change your code to this:

```
$weekly_savings = "100";
$goal = "5000";
$progress = "500"
$NPER = round(PHPExcel_Calculation_Financial::NPER(.002/12,($weekly_savings*4),($goal - $progress))*-1,2);
for ($x = 0; $x <= $NPER; $x++) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $FV = round(PHPExcel_Calculation_Financial::FV(.002/12,1,$weekly_savings*4,$progress)*-1,2);
    $weekly_savings = $FV;

}
```